# Modification in a WCF application not working

Tags: c#, wcf

My question is about "Why is my modification not working?" rather than "How to create a chat application in WCF?"

[**Here is the entire source code after modification.**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U0WCabFzg5npb-ciX-ycEHrW3uQQM6_C/view?usp=sharing).

I have modified [this application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17321/A-simple-peer-to-peer-chat-application-using-WCF-n) so that the GUI and Service-engine could be decoupled.

I.e. `ChatClient`

```
public partial class ChatClient : Form, IChatService
{
}
```

is separated into several files, and `ChatClient` is renamed into `ChatClientForm`:

```
public class ChatClientForm {}
public class ChatService : IChatService{}
public interface IChatChannel : IChatService, IClientChannel {}
public interface IChatService{}
```

Now, the problem is: the server starts and the user is being able to login, but are not being able to send and receive messages.

[image]

What am I missing there?

Comment: WCF is about communications, not the UI. You'll have to write code in your classes that raises events or displayes message boxes when your service receives a request

Comment: One way to do that would be to add events to IChatService and raise them when a request is received. If the form has a reference to the service, eg stored in a field, it will be easy to add event handlers in the form itself, and modify the UI there

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question itself. Links die. In any case, SO is about programming questions. `codereview.stackexchange.com` is the appropriate site for code reviews.

Comment: Right now someone would have to follow those links and debug an entire application just to understand what the question is. The relevant code though should only be a few lines - the form fields, handlers, service code

Comment: Yes, I know it's Pastebin, which means they'll be lost after a while. I also know I'd have to download all that just to understand the question

Comment: If it's not working, there would have to be a point in the application where it's crashing, or a specific error being returned if it fails to build at all.  Listing those would help people to diagnose the issue.  As @Panagiotis said, currently this expects someone to debug an entire application, not find the error in a couple lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your question is about a chat application (instead of polling all the time ), you can use [Duplex Services in WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services), 
this will allow you to send the data to the server and allow the server to sen teh data back to your application, there should be a lot of examples on the net on using this service type in a chat application, one such you can find on

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25261/A-WCF-WPF-Chat-Application

The idea is to have a channel open that the server can reply to when there is a message sent to it from the other clients

Comment: My question is about "Why is my modification not working?" rather than "How to create a chat application in WCF?"